# htcaccess Rewrite Rule not working in any way

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a project and I’m trying to do a URL rewrite in the root of my website. The `.htaccess` as it is now is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/([^/]+) /screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/index.php?id=$1
```

Rewrite is enabled on my site. I have checked the code through [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) and it shows the correct values.

Yet when I visit `screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/123` for an example, I get a 404 page. When I visit `screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/` it works just fine.

Also, when going to the "real" URL manually, it also works as expected: `screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/index.php?id=123`

I can’t seem to figure out where the problem is and have tried moving the `.htaccess` to other folders and of course also editing the path, yet no success.

Any other troubleshooting tips anyone can give? How can I check what the redirect actually is doing in the background?

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled and also .htacess support is enabled via `AllowOverride` setting? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I'm very certain of that, on another project with the same host my rewrite works as expected and I checked the settings and compared them with both sites and can't see any differences, that's why I don't understand where the problem lies.

Comment: What is generating the 404 response? Apache or your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/([^/]+) /screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/index.php?id=$1
> ```

The "problem" with this rule is that is also matches the rewritten URL (specifically, `[^/]+` matches `index.php`) so gets rewritten a second time to `/screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/index.php?id=index.php` (the `id=123` parameter is overwritten). So, I would expect *your script* to be generating the 404 response (not Apache)?

To resolve this, you should make the regex more specific and/or use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4) to prevent an additional loop (and second rewrite) by the rewrite engine.

In your example you are passing a numeric value - so if you are only expecting a numeric value then match digits only.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/(\d+)$ /screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/index.php?id=$1 [END]
```

Note that I also included the trailing `$` on the regex, otherwise your site is open to abuse since *anything* could be appended to the URL and the same resource would be served. (In your original rule appending `/<anything>` would result in the same response.)

(I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root.)

---

> I have checked the code through htaccess tester and it shows the correct values.

The MWL tester only makes a single pass through the file. This is not how a real Apache server works. Consequently the MWL tester is unable to detect rewrite/redirect loops.

> When I visit `screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/` it works just fine.

When you visit `screenshot-of-the-week/screenshot/` then the rule is not processed (the regex does not match). mod_dir serves the `DirectoryIndex` document (`index.php`), but without the `id` parameter.